# Почему здесь получается 38, а не 93?

Tags: python

```
def positive_sum(arr):
    for i in arr:
        if i < 0:
            arr.remove(i)
    return sum(arr)



print(positive_sum([91, -63, 2, -87, -55, -23]))
```

Как сделать так, чтобы функция игнорировала все отрицательные числа и суммировала положительные? Почему в более простых примерах работает и выдаёт правильную сумму, а где больше значений неправильную?

Comment: "Шо, опять?" Кажется, был уже миллион вопросов, где итерируются по списку и из него же удаляют :)

Answer (score 3):

До кучи, в порядке прикола:

```
arr = [91, -63, 2, -87, -55, -23]
print(sum(filter((0).__lt__, arr)))
# 93
```

Фильтруем числа, оставляя такие `x`, что `0 < x` и суммируем что получилось.

Comment: что означает (0).__lt__?

Comment: @Universall У любых объектов питона есть встроенные методы. В частности у объектов типа `int` они тоже есть. К сожалению, если написать просто `0.функция`, то питон подумает, что я неправильно написал число с плавающей точкой, поэтому нужны скобки `(0).функция`. Ну а `__lt__` это встроенный метод сравнения "меньше". Т.е. я через `filter` проверяю "0 меньше" для каждого элемента `arr`. Код короткий, а объяснение длинное ))

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Я просто с выражением (0). не сталкивался)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали в комментариях:

> Вы идёте по списку и параллельно его модифицируете.

Правильнее будет сделать так:

```
def positive_sum(arr):
    my_sum = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i > 0:
            my_sum += i
    return my_sum


print(positive_sum([91, -63, 2, -87, -55, -23]))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что *"пилите сук на котором сидите"*. Вы идёте по списку и параллельно его модифицируете. Оттого некоторые элементы пропускаются (потому что они сдвинулись левее).

Если распечатывать `print(i, arr)` список каждый раз, когда вы из него удаляете элемент, то легко это заметить.

```
-63 [91, 2, -87, -55, -23]
-87 [91, 2, -55, -23]
-23 [91, 2, -55]
```

Обнаружили -63, удалили, на его место встала 2. Но ей повезло, что она положительная, т.к. на следующей итерации проверяется уже -87. Удаляется -87, на её место встаёт -55. Но на следующей итерации следующий элемент уже -23, а -55 "пропустили".

И вообще, проще (и быстрее) фильтровать значения по критерию при проходе, чем модифицировать исходный список.

```
def positive_sum(arr):
    return sum(item for item in arr if item >= 0)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код может в принципе сработать если его немного подправить. Например, примерно так:

```
def positive_sum(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)-1,-1,-1):
        if arr[i] < 0:
            arr.remove(arr[i])
    return sum(arr)
```

Это в случае если нужно не просто найти сумму положительных, но и заодно зачистить в исходном списке отрицательные числа. Так как в результате работы функции получится это:

```
nums = [91, -63, 2, -87, -55, -23]
print(positive_sum(nums))
'''
93
'''
print(f'{nums = }')
'''
nums = [91, 2]
```